# Git soft reset following revert deleted files changes

Tags: git

I wanted to undo a commit, using IntelliJ I right-clicked on the last commit and then clicked "Revert Commit". A message told me no changes were made. By looking at the command log the command was:

```
revert 75d72c1c0746b225d3857 --no-commit
```

The reverted changes appear in the changelist (or in the staged files area using sourcetree).
I realized it wasn't the correct command to do what I needed, so I used:

```
reset --soft HEAD^
```

The last commit was eliminated, but the edited files did not appear in the changelist. It was as if I executed a `reset --hard`.

I managed to recover changes in another way, but I don't understand why the soft reset acted as a hard reset.

Comment: What do you mean by "the edited files did not appear in the changelist"? How are you viewing this "changelist"?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ, it's the area where I see changed files. Now I noticed that after executing a revert --no-commit on the last commit, the reverted file appears in the changelist (or in the staged files area using sourcetree). Then if I execute the reset --soft in that state, the reset is applied as if it's reset --hard (changes are lost).

Comment: MCVE: `git init; touch foo; git add foo; git commit -m "add foo"; echo "hello" >> foo; git commit -am "modify foo"; git revert --no-commit HEAD; git reset --soft HEAD~`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use a modified version of the example that @0x5453 gave in a comment:

```
git init
echo "hello\n" >> foo
git add foo
git commit -m "add foo"
echo "goodbye\n" >> foo
git commit -am "modify foo"
```

At this point, the file `foo` has the following contents:

```
hello
goodbye
```

And we have two commits, one for each line in the file.

Now, when you do

```
git revert --no-commit HEAD
```

This "undoes" the changes in the most recent commit. This appears as local changes that haven't been committed. If you do `git status`, you will see that `foo` is modified. Its contents are now

```
hello
```

which is the exact same as the first commit.

So now when you do

```
git reset --soft HEAD~
```

You reset back to the first commit. But since the contents of the file are exactly the same as that commit, you will not see any local changes.

Comment: So I understand that even if taken alone, neither revert nor restore -soft would cause you to lose the changes, taken together they do. This is because revert acts on the local copy of the files and restore acts on the repository.